# how to navigate back to parent?

Tags: android

I have main activity, in the main activity I can choose to what activity I want to go next: A, B, C, D then when I choose an activity (no matter which one) I get in activity E, from activity E I want to navigate back to the parent.
    I don't know how is the parent the called E so I can't write in the manifest file.

For example: main activity -> A -> E or main Activity-> C-> E

This what I wrote in E activity:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
           NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And in manifest file:

```
    <activity android:name=".EActivity" 
    android:label="@string/bNowPlaying"
                      android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            </activity>
```

Comment: Have tried simply calling `onBackPressed()`  instead of `finish()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed :      NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
and it works ! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a button with an `OnClickListener()` and `finish();` the current activity :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              finish();  
          });
```

Comment: where do I need to add this, in onOptionsItemSelected function?

Comment: Oh, I don't seen that you have finish(); in your onOptionItemSelected, so can you explain more what is happenning when you execute android.R.id.home action please?

Comment: It crashes when I want to go back

Comment: Can you edit the quastion by providing the stacktrace please?